# Does the Downloads folder always exist?

Tags: filesystem

Is a user's downloads folder always called "Downloads" and located in the same path, or does its name and path change due to localization?

Comment: It kind of depends *why* you want it. It may not be set to the system default, as it is a user-modifiable parameter. Programatically, you'd need to be looking at NSURLs [which is off-topic here, I'm afraid]

Answer (score 4):

It changes according to localization, but just the name as all the default folders in OS X, the path is the same.

**Macintosh HD/Users/user_name/Downloads**

Answer (score 0):

It does not change, and always exists by default. On-screen finder labels might be localised, but on the actual file system the name remains “Downloads”.